# Rewriting UDP packets on Linux

Tags: rewrite, udp

I would like to rewrite the contents/payload of UDP packets as they are received by a machine, on selected reports - before they are passed to the listening application.

For example, I would like to change the headers of a UDP-based protocol by using grep-like regular expressions (to add, remove or change parts of each message received).

Is this possible with a software firewall or similar tool?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't for production, but rather just learning.  I recommend [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), you can craft and replay packets on a object oriented interface that relates to the OSI model.  It acts like an interactive python console.   You can also sniff with it, lots of fun ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Such a tool is called a UDP Proxy and there are a few out there.

- Simple UDP Proxy/Pipe
- udpproxy
- UProxy

Comment: Thanks, DigitalRoss. These last two look like they do forwarding of UDP only, rather than allowing rewrites of the payload. Is that so?

What do you mean by "Simple UDP Proxy/Pipe". Pipe to a userland program?

Comment: Ah, I see it is actually the name of a package!

Answer (score 0):

TRIPP may also be a solution:

http://tripp.dynalias.org/